# how can i to add items to an already created Array

Tags: c#, arrays

i have string array as the following
string[] strArray = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "5", "6" };
the question is
how can i add item to this created Array at specific position
to be like
{ "1", "2", "3" , "4" , "5", "6" }
i need some thing can append value at specific index and keep the old values

Comment: Make a larger array and put the items in

Comment: use a List<string> it has an Add Method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this, since arrays have fixed length after creation. Use [`List<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead (which internally stores its items in array):

```
var strList = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "5", "6" };
strList.Insert(2, "foo");
```

If you'll need to convert the list into array, use `ToArray` extension method:

```
var strArray = strList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are immutable, but Lists are not:

```
var list = strArray.ToList();
list.Add("6")
strArray = list.ToArray();
```

Or, at a specific index:

```
var list = strArray.ToList();
list.Insert(3, "4");
strArray = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Neither `Add` nor `Insert` returns the list.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen well maybe they should :P ... corrected, thanks.